# Storing a memory address into a register

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying to implement a program which checks whether an element is present into an "array" or not, but when I try to execute it, it always says the element isn't present, even though it is.
Here's the code:

```
;
; Subroutine to search for a value in an array
; Input: 
;  - R2: the base array address
;  - R3: the number of elements in the array
;  - R4: the value to look for
; Output: in R1, the address of the found value, or zero if nothing was found

.ORIG 0x300
NUM_1: .FILL 0x032
NUM_2: .FILL 0x00A
NUM_3: .FILL 0x009
NUM_4: .FILL 0x025
N: .FILL 0x004
SEARCH_VALUE: .FILL 0x032

LEA R2, NUM_1
LD R3, N
LD R4, SEARCH_VALUE

FIND: 
        AND R1, R1, #0    ; Zero out R1 in case we find nothing
        ADD R3, R2, R3    ; We turn R3 from the number of elements of the array into
                      ; the address of the word just past the end of the array
    
LOOP:
        NOT R5, R3
    ADD R5, R5, #1
    ADD R5, R5, R2 

    BRZ EXIT ; if (R2==R3)
    LDR R5, R2, #0
    NOT R5, R5
    ADD R5, R5, #1
    ADD R5, R4, R5
    BRNP LOOP ; if(R5!=R4)
    LDR R1, R2, #0
    ADD R2, R2, #1 ;R2++

EXIT:
        HALT
        .END
```

I suppose the problems is when I try to store into the register R2 the memory address of NUM_1, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You want `LEA R2, NUM_1` not `LDI R2, NUM_1`. Use your simulator to single step the code, you should have seen the problem at the very first instruction. PS: you don't have subroutines so don't use `JSR` (even though it works)

Comment: If I try to use JMP it displays me this error: Expected register operand, but found 'LOOP' instead

Comment: Have you tried to single step debug yet?  If not, now is the time.

Comment: You want `BRnzp` for unconditional branching. `JMP` is for indirect jumps.

Comment: I've fixed those problems and tried a single step debug, it never assigns to R1 any value (not even if I put it under the END label, which is always executed)
P.S. I edited the code above

Comment: The LEA does its job anyway, I checked and the cycle ends when R2 reaches 772 (which is the decimal equivalent of hex 304)

Comment: The original code worked for me if I changed to the `LEA`.

Comment: Oh really? Let me check then, I probably missed something in this second version.

Comment: This one does not work because `ADD R5, R4, #0` should be `ADD R5, R4, R5`. Also you increment `R2` before checking the first element which is a bug.

Comment: Exactly, thank you, if you write the answer to the question I'll accept it.